# Python API Post Request URL Returning Error

Tags: python, api, web-applications, python-requests

I'm trying to use this service, Buffer, to publish a post on Facebook through API.

Here's my code:

```
params = {
    'profile_ids': ids,
    'text': "text",
    'access_token': access_token
}

r = requests.post('https://api.bufferapp.com/1/updates/create.json', params=params)
print r.json()
print(r.url)
```

But when run I it, it prints out this message:

```
{"success":false,"message":"Please select at least one account to post from.","code":1004}

This is the URL used to make the request:
https://api.bufferapp.com/1/updates/create.json?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&text=TEXT&profile_ids=LIST_WITH_PROFILE_IDS
```

I made sure the id is correct and I got it both manually and through API still, I get the same message.

The only required parameter is the profile_ids which should be an array. Here's the documentation on their website about publishing posts("updates"): https://buffer.com/developers/api/updates

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the API expects the data in the `post` request payload, not as url parameters.

Use `data`, not `params`.

```
r = requests.post('https://api.bufferapp.com/1/updates/create.json', data=params)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^ here
```